# Dockerfile permission for volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM maven:3.8.5-eclipse-temurin-17 AS builder

WORKDIR /server
COPY pom.xml /server/pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline

COPY src /server/src
RUN mvn install


# install Docker tools (cli, buildx, compose)
COPY --from=gloursdocker/docker / /
CMD ["mvn", "spring-boot:run"]

FROM builder as prepare-production
RUN mkdir -p target/dependency
WORKDIR /server/target/dependency
RUN jar -xf ../*.jar

FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jre-focal

EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /app
ARG DEPENDENCY=/server/target/dependency
COPY --from=prepare-production ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/lib /app/lib
COPY --from=prepare-production ${DEPENDENCY}/META-INF /app/META-INF
COPY --from=prepare-production ${DEPENDENCY}/BOOT-INF/classes /app
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-cp","app:app/lib/*","com.server.backend.BackendApplicaiton"]
```

and I need to save the files in /app to the /opt/containers/backend directory (absolute). Code bellow is my docker compose file.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    container_name: "backend"
    build: backend
    environment:
      - ${MSSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 3000:8080
    volumes:
      - /opt/containers/backend:/app
    networks:
      - backend
networks:
  backend:
    name: backend
    driver: bridge
    internal: false
```

if I run this and create volume in docker, everything works, files are saved inside docker volume, but when I set absolute path as in the docker compose file, directory is empty and app does not run. I am sure the error is in permissions, but I cant figured it out where and I could not find any solutions :(

Thank you for all your replies and help.

Comment: `ls -la /opt/containers`?

Comment: I wrote its empty

Comment: the output to my command would also show the owner and rights. it's good if you post the output

Comment: Owner is root now, but I tried to chown the directory before for docker so 1000. The same i tried to create new user in Dockerfile and chown the dir with it without change. Permissions are drwxr-xr-x, but again I tried chmod 777 with -R without change

Comment: are you on macos by any chance?

Comment: can you check volume definition by `docker volume inspect my-volume` maybe something wrong with the creation of that volume.

Comment: No linux, debian 11

Comment: If I will use docker volume (docker create) and mount it to docker container it works. It does not work when I use absolute path as in the docker compose file above.